# Caracteres latinos C++ Python API error | UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, c++, api

Estoy intentando llamar a un método de una clase de Python desde C++, y uno de los argumentos es un str que en este caso la cadena es "Se forma Línea". Me está largando un error que hace referencia al acento en la í. Como puedo pasar en los argumentos cadenas con caracteres latinos?

Esta es la línea de código que está fallando. Es el argumento evento.c_str()

```
PyObject_CallMethod(objeto_PythonEscenario, "setEventoLinea", "sd", evento.c_str(), pendiente);
```

Este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy corriendo en Visual Studio, Windows 7 con Python 3.7

**Edición 1 -----------------------------------------------------------------------**

Cambié un par de cosas y lo mas cercano que logré al resultado que quiero fue esto

Código en C++

```
void setEventoLinea(string evento, double pendiente)
{
PyObject_CallMethod(objeto_PythonEscenario, "setEventoLinea", "ud", evento.c_str(), pendiente);
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
}
```

Está sería la función completa en C++. Cambie el argumento "sd" por "ud". "u" convierte la cadena a formato unicode y ya no me está tirando el error

Código en Python

```
def setEventoLinea(self, evento, pendiente):
   print(evento.encode('utf-16'))
```

Aún no estoy usando el argumento pendiente porque primero quiero solucionar lo de la cadena.

Esto me imprime lo siguiente en la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cadena debería ser: "Se forma Línea de Resistencia"

Comment: Más que con los caracteres latinos, es un problema de codificación, seguro en un lado tienes UTF-8 y en el otro ISO-8859-1 o cualquier otro, en tu función ¿no hay forma de decirle en qué codificación está lo que envías?

Comment: Te referís a la función en python? Estuve buscando pero no encontré nada muy útil hasta el momento. Lo que leí es que la codificación de python es por defecto utf-8, y de la cadena que se envía, el único caracter que presenta problemas es la "í", porque envié otras cadenas y las lee perfectamente dado que todos los caracteres son utf-8. Lo que estaba tratando de encontrar es alguna forma de convertir el utf-8 del lado de C++ a otro codec que contenga todos los caracteres que necesito, pero nada por ahora

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694994/utf-8-on-windows-python